# Autoscrolling after timeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-applications

I have an element, of id `list` that I want to auto scroll to the bottom and then back to the top continuously, but should stop scrolling to allow the user to control scroll. After a certain amount of time that the user has not `"mousemove mousedown"` on the element, the element should begin to auto scroll again.

I'm having difficulty managing the timeouts(for auto scroll up after auto scroll down) and interval(for continues autoscrolling up and down) and "mousemove mousedown" events and stopping the animation once those events occur. My code was a jumbled mess.

My scroll down:

```
$("#list").animate({
scrollTop : $("#list")[0].scrollHeight
}, timeDown);
```

Scroll up:

```
$("#list").animate({
    scrollTop : 0
}, timeUp);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsbin.com/oqadud/3/edit

```
$list   = $('#list');
$listSH = $list[0].scrollHeight - $list.outerHeight();

function loop(){ 
  var t = $list.scrollTop();
  $list.stop().animate({scrollTop : !t ? $listSH : 0 }, 2000, loop);
}
loop();

$list.on('mouseenter mouseleave', function( e ){
  return e.type=="mouseenter"? $list.stop() : loop();
});
```

`$listSH` will return actually the Available scrollHeight, than you can use the `animate` callback to recall the `function loop()` that will loop our animation.

inside the `loop` we just need to get the current `$list.scrollTop();` position - in case of mouseleave or any other circumstance so we can ask a `ternary operator ( ? : )` what to do in case the boolean `!t (is0==false)` animate to `$listSH` else animate to `0`.

on DOM ready you call/start your `loop()`

and on `'mouseenter mouseleave'` grab the event and again inside a ternary operator do:
**IF** event == `mouseenter` : `.stop()` any animation
**ELSE** : restart our `loop()` function (as I said, from the current `scrollTop()`).

Comment: This is great. I was looking for a timeout rather than mouseenter mouseleave. I just added in a settimeout. And how would I go about setting the time for autoscroll up and time for autoscroll down?

Comment: @Anonymous what time? YOu can change the `2000` to whatever you need

Comment: I wanted separate up and down scroll speeds. I figured it out though, I just added a ternary operator: !t ? timeDown : timeUp where 2000 was.